# Xamarin.Forms Open Notification OnClick with same info

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am using **Xamarin.forms** on android project, I am trying to push notification and it is working fine, but I am searching away to allow user to show notification on full screen size with same title and same content(maybe I need to open it on anew android activity?! ) 
on the following my code:

```
var notification = new Notification.Builder (Application.Context)
                .SetContentTitle (message.Short_Message.ToString ())
                .SetContentText (message.Long_Message.ToString())
                .SetSmallIcon (Resource.Mipmap.ic_launcher)  
                .SetStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().BigText(message.Long_Message))   
                .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.Max)                      
                .Build ();

            var manager = Application.Context.GetSystemService (Application.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
            manager.Notify (message.ID, notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, we use the native projects as little as possible.
When people click the notification, we take them to the forms app and show the info.

Is there a particular reason you are not opening the forms project to show the content? you can just inject your properties into the App class.

If you, for some reason need to stay in the Android project, I am fairly sure you need to open a new activity. Notifications are exacyly what they sound like - a notification, ot a full page view. You can just tranfer your values in the bundle.

Comment: could you please add code  explain how i can do that by open anew activity

Answer (score 0):

please check bellow code:

```
var manager =
    (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);

var intent =
    context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(context.PackageName);
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);

var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

var message = "Hello, Sigma!";
var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .SetSmallIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.TitleBar)
    .SetContentTitle("Hello!")
    .SetStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().BigText(message))
    .SetContentText(message)
    .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

manager.Notify(1, builder.Build());
```